# Transform all escaped chars to its original value

Tags: javascript, escaping

My backend has json string arrays, but some of the chars are escaped when send the value to frontend, like " é. How can I change all of the escaped chars to its original value? For some reason, I can't use other JS frameworks. The innerHTML seems didn't be supported in all browsers(like firefox).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet to unescape the string

```js
//Snippet#1
var str="é";
var str_esc=escape(str);
document.write("Escaped String: " + str_esc + "<br>")
document.write("Original String: " + unescape(str_esc))
```

or

```js
//Snippet#2
var str="é";
var enc_str = encodeURI(str);
var dec_str = decodeURI(enc_str);

document.write("Escaped String: " + enc_str + "<br>")
document.write("Original String: " + dec_str)
```